# Find an analogue of Weyl chamber structure

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reductive-groups, root-systems

Let $G$ be a split reductive group and let $T$ be a split maximal torus whose rank is $l$. Is it possible to find a base $\gamma_1,..., \gamma_l$ of the weight lattice $X(T)$ such that the cone $C$ in the coweight lattice $Y(T)$ defined by
$$C=\{\psi\in Y(T)\vert (\psi, \gamma_i)\geq 0\; i=1,...,l\}$$
forms a complete fan under the translation of the Weyl group in $Y(T)$?

If $G$ is an adjoint group, such a base is provided by simple roots and $C$ is simply the positive Weyl chamber. How about the general reductive group?

Comment: I don't know the definition of "complete fan", and it's hard to Google, but my suspicion is that for a simply connected group the fundamental weights will do, and that one can show rigorously that such a choice cannot always exist for groups intermediate between adjoint and simply connected (in somewhat the same spirit as maximally split tori in quasi-split adjoint or simply connected groups must be induced, but the statement fails for intermediate groups).

Comment: Sorry for anbiguous description; by complete fan, I mean the union of all polyhedral cones in this fan covers the fan itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that the translates of C form a complete fan seems to imply that $C$ is a fundamental domain for the Weyl group: The translates cover space, and they form a fan, meaning the intersection of any two translates has lower dimension.

The Weyl group is generated by reflections. The interior of a fundamental domain can't intersect the fixed hyperplanes of these reflections, because then the intersection of the domain with its translate by that reflection must have full dimension. Since the fundamental domain is a cone, its interior is connected, and thus lies in a single connected component of the complement of these hyperplanes, i.e. a single Weyl chamber. Since its translates cover the space, it must make up a full Weyl chamber. So $C$ must be a Weyl chamber.

After translating, we can assume $C$ is the standard Weyl chamber. This happens only if the $\gamma_i$s are positive real multiples of the simple roots.

So this is possible if and only if the least positive multiples of the simple roots that lie in the weight lattice in fact form a basis for the weight lattice. This fails, for example, for $SL_n$.